# Should i be using the device height and width or the viewport with compass extension breakpoint?

Tags: media-queries, breakpoint-sass

So I have the following situation :
$iphone : 320px (max-height 568px); 
This is the iphone dimensions. However, when i resize my browser to these exact values the media queries won't work. If i input the viewport instead of this by checking the display size using a browser extension it works. Should i be using device width and height or the viewport ? Seems weird to use the viewport.

Here is an example of my variables for breakpoint : Am i fixing the issue by adding "device" ? Do I have to add "device" to all of them ?

> /* Motorola RAZR V8 (240 x 320) */
>
> $motorola-portrait : 240px (max-device-height 320px);
>
> /* Blackberry 8300 (320 x 240) */
>
> $blackberry-portrait : 320px (max-device-height 240px);
>
> /* iphone 3-4  (320 x 480) */
>
> $iphone4-portrait :  320px (max-device-height 480px);
>
> /* iphone 5  (320 x 568) */
>
> $iphone5-portrait : 320px (max-device-height 568px);
>
> /* Sasmung Galaxy S3/S4 (360 x 640) */
>
> $samsunggalaxy-portrait : 360px (max-device-height 640px);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On this site you can test your media queries

[Media Query Tester](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/)

You don't have to do for all devices! Just do it for a range!